# IWAB0014E Unexpected exception occurred using apache-cxf

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, cxf, eclipse-wtp

I am trying to create a simple soap web service application using **Eclipse - Spring tools Suite**
(4.10.0.RELEASE) and I encountered this error.

I am using **Tomcat v10.0 server**, and **Apache-CXF-3.4.3**. Can anyone please help me out with this exception?

IWAB0014E Unexpected exception occurred.

````
  Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource.getFullPath()" because "srcDirectoryResource" is null
      java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource.getFullPath()" because "srcDirectoryResource" is null
      at org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.core.utils.JDTUtils.getJavaProjectSourceDirectoryPath(JDTUtils.java:159)
      at org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.core.utils.JDTUtils.getJavaProjectSourceDirectoryPath(JDTUtils.java:146)
      at org.eclipse.jst.ws.internal.cxf.creation.core.commands.WSDL2JavaDefaultingCommand.execute(WSDL2JavaDefaultingCommand.java:111)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.runCommand(CommandFragmentEngine.java:421)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.visitTop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:361)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.core.fragment.CommandFragmentEngine.moveForwardToNextStop(CommandFragmentEngine.java:256)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager$6.run(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:296)
      at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:436)
      at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:352)
      at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1033)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleCommandEngineManager.runForwardToNextStop(SimpleCommandEngineManager.java:266)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.runForwardToNextStop(WizardPageManager.java:93)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.WizardPageManager.getNextPage(WizardPageManager.java:156)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.SimpleWizardPage.getNextPage(SimpleWizardPage.java:138)
      at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.nextPressed(WizardDialog.java:910)
      at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:468)
      at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.lambda$0(Dialog.java:619)
      at org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener$1.widgetSelected(SelectionListener.java:84)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:252)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4209)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1043)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4026)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3626)
      at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:823)
      at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:799)
      at org.eclipse.wst.command.internal.env.ui.widgets.popup.DynamicPopupWizard.run(DynamicPopupWizard.java:132)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:239)
      at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:580)
      at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$4(ActionContributionItem.java:414)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4209)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1043)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4026)
      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3626)
      at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1157)
      at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
      at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
      at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
      at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
      at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
      at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1461)```
````

Answer (score 1):

Looks like https://bugs.eclipse.org/570817. You can manually edit the project's `.classpath` file so that the source folder entry is first, or update the underlying Eclipse to 2021-06 and WTP 3.22.